# roscpp parameters with roslaunch remapping

Tags: roslaunch, remapping, parameter, remap, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I access roscpp parameters if the node name has been remapped with roslaunch?

launch file,

```
<node pkg="my_package" type="my_package_node" name="remapped_name" ns="my_namespace">
    <param name="camera_index" value="$(arg camera_index)" />
</node>
```

in cpp file,

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "node_default_name");
ros::NodeHandle n;
    
ros::param::get("node_default_name/camera_index", camera_index); // Fails
ros::param::get("remapped_name/camera_index", camera_index); // Works 

n.getParam("node_default_name/camera_index", camera_index); // Fails
n.getParam("remapped_name/camera_index", camera_index); // Works
```

How can I get the parameters in the .cpp file without knowing the node name?  Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135181/roscpp-parameters-with-roslaunch-remapping/) by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should use the private namespace:

```
ros::param::get("~camera_index", camera_index);

ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
nh.getParam("camera_index", camera_index);
```

see http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on 2014-03-05**:
Yep, worked for me, thanks!
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
nh.getParam("camera_index", camera_index);